# Applying mysql conditions

Tags: mysql

I have used two tables invoice and payment.
I tried to generate paid, due and unpaid status.

The following is my query, This will give all invoices and total payments.
How can i apply a condition to filter paid, due, unpaid.
I cant give as paid amount 
Following is successful query:

```
select a.*, sum(b.amount) as paidamount from tbl_invoices a left join tbl_billpayment b on a.invoiceno = b.invoiceno where a.id != '' GROUP BY b.invoiceno ORDER BY a.billdate DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

This will give error

```
select a.*, sum(b.amount) as paidamount from tbl_invoices a left join tbl_billpayment b on a.invoiceno = b.invoiceno where a.id != '' and ( paidamount >= a.total)
```

> Notice: Error: Unknown column 'paidamount' in 'where clause'

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this condition.

```
( paidamount >= a.total)
```

instead use like this

```
(sum(b.amount) >=a.total)
```

paidamount is just an alias that will replace name while projection.

Comment: HAVING  sum(b.amount) >= a.total will give me paid results, Thank you!.

Answer (score 2):

`paidamount` is just an alias in results, but it's not available in the `WHERE` clause.

You have to use the same expression `sum(b.amount)` instead of that `paidamount` alias

```
select a.*, sum(b.amount) as paidamount 
from tbl_invoices a 
left join tbl_billpayment b on a.invoiceno = b.invoiceno 
where a.id != '' and ( sum(b.amount) >= a.total)
```

Moreover this actually won't work properly either, since you're using aggregate function in `WHERE` clause.

`WHERE` *happens* **before** grouping, while `SUM` value is calculated per group.
I guess you want to use `HAVING` clause here.

```
select a.*, sum(b.amount) as paidamount 
from tbl_invoices a 
left join tbl_billpayment b on a.invoiceno = b.invoiceno 
where a.id != ''
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING  sum(b.amount) >= a.total
```